# Julia - How to pass kwargs from a function to a macro

Tags: function, arguments, julia

You can define a function to pass its keyword arguments to inner functions like this:

```
function example(data;xcol,ycol,kwargs...)
    DoSomething(; spec=:EX, x=xcol, y=ycol, kwargs...)
end
```

Now, the function `DoSomething` accepts many arguments, such as `color`. This works for functions, but I'd like to do this with a macro from VegaLite.jl:

```
function example(data;xcol,ycol,kwargs...)
    @vlplot(data=data,mark=:point, x=xcol, y=ycol,kwargs...)
end
example(df,xcol=:Miles_per_Gallon, ycol=:Horsepower, color=:Origin)
```

Note that the code above does not work.

Comment: You mean the @vlplot? That is the way VegaLite.jl works. Don't think it has a function counterpart

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I had already deleted that comment after realizing it's an established API you want to call.

Comment: I think that the answer to the question is that if `example` is a function then this is not possible. `example` would have to be a macro to allow it. Note that macros do not accept keyword arguments as they only accept expressions as arguments. I guess this is what Matt B. wanted to express - right?

Comment: You may dynamically construct the expression and `eval` it.

Comment: Using `eval` is possible, but it would get evaluated in a different scope then which has to be taken into account when designing the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the answer here is... it's tricky.  And in fact, in general, this isn't possible *unless the macro itself supports it*.

See, macros do their transformations at parse time — and often will exploit what you've *actually written* to mean something different and special.  For example, `@vlplot` will specially handle and support JSON-like `{}` syntaxes.  These aren't valid Julia code and can't be passed to a function you define (like `example`)!

Now, it's tempting to see this and think, ok, let's make that outer `example` thing into a macro, too!  But it's not that easy.  I'm not sure it's possible to have a general answer that will always pass the arguments appropriately *and* get the hygiene correct.  I'm pretty sure you need to know something about how the macro you're calling handles its arguments.

Answer (score 6):

you need to add `;` before `kwargs` to signal they are `kwargs` not positional arguments e.g.:

```
DoSomething(;spec=:EX, x=xcol, y=ycol, kwargs...)
```

(this is the answer for `DoSomething` being a function as this was the original formulation of the question)

Comment: If I use the splatter, I get the following error:
"syntax: unexpected semicolon in array expression around In[50]:2"

Comment: Just to be more precise, in my case, DoSomething is actually a macro.

Comment: Can you please show a fully reproducible example of your code, as otherwise it is hard do know exactly what you need.

Comment: Yeah, sure. So I'm using VegaLite.jl. I edited the question with the example. The comment was not properly formatted.

Comment: Yeah, in this case there's a huge difference between functions and macros — I've further edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would work the same way. My mistake.

Comment: No problem - actually this is a good question, as these issues are quite tricky.